# Aceder sub div JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
     <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Lights</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div id="relay">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Este é o meu HTML, e eu pretendo adicionar um botão na div `relay`, mas não sei como aceder a ela com javascript.

O meu javascript é algo como isto

```
if(1 == 1){ //ignorem esta comparação
    document.getElementById('relay').innerHTML='<button type='button'  class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-danger'>OFF</button>';
}else{ 
    document.getElementById('relay').innerHTML='<button type='button' class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-success'>ON</button>';
}
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolvera questão? Se sim, por favor marque a resposta. Obg!

Answer (score 3):

Tem que usar aspas duplas para delimitar a string, já que dentro dela você está usando aspas simples:

```
...="<button type='button'  class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-danger'>OFF</button>";
    ↑                                                                                   ↑
```

Nesta linha também:

```
...="<button type='button' class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-success'>ON</button>";
    ↑                                                                                  ↑
```

Ou então terias que escapar todas as aspas simples da string, o que não é a melhor saída:

```
...='<button type=\'button\' class=\'btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-success\'>ON</button>';
```

Comment: utilizei aspas simples, porque este código está incorporado no arduino, e por sua vez, cada linha já esta com aspas duplas tipo isto `javaScript+="   message = xmldoc[0].firstChild.nodeValue;\n";`

Comment: Entendi... só um instante que vou verificar...

Comment: Então faz como coloquei na resposta mesmo, mas escape as aspas duplas, assim: `document.getElementById('relay').innerHTML=\"<button type='button'  class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-danger'>OFF</button>\";`

Comment: faço escape só no inicio e no fim? acho que te enganas-te a escrever...

Comment: Se eu entendi a questão, creio que seja escapando as duas aspas duplas. Esse código está dentro da variável `javaScript`, não é isso?

Comment: Sim é isso. Mas a maneira de adicionar o `<button>` à `div relay` é da maneira questoua  fazer com o `document.getElementById('relay').innerHTML=...` ?

Comment: Sim, é uma forma de fazer isso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76237/discussion-between-xeoon-and-dvd).

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?